# Reddit api/random always returns the same thing, I cannot figure out why - this seems to only be happening on my computer

Tags: javascript, api, reddit

Im trying to get a random subreddit from reddits api every 10 minutes (not in this code). But with this code it always returns the same subreddit! I don't know what the problem is :(

```
  $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/random/.json', function (item) {
  console.log(item[0].data.children[0].data.subreddit)
})
```

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: we need to see the rest of the code, where are you saving the subreddit? I just pasted that exact code into the console and it works, kept submitting it and it returns random every time...

Comment: Right now im not saving the subreddit, im just testing to see if it works. Really weird that it works for you.

Comment: I changed nothing...you are telling me it doesnt work for you in the console?

Comment: Nope, proof: https://i.gyazo.com/6c4cac9c697feabf22772eb46b0cfc51.png

Comment: wow ok I believe you now, can you try a different browse incognito tab, this is odd!

Comment: Same in Edge: https://gyazo.com/aa8105ae5c389c091b0309a1462f9a82

Comment: Im going to download firefox and try, 1 sec.

Comment: Same in Firefox: https://gyazo.com/dbf9954029462c41ab6732eec67ccebe

Comment: Same in incognito: https://gyazo.com/1d3f9ebaf2dcd8968e868a70edfa1e2c

Comment: I have not idea whats going on, sorry, this is a pretty unusual problem, I'm gonna edit the post to get some more views...

Comment: Can you try multiple computers in the same network?  Can you try moving one of the computers (if it's a laptop or mobile device) to a different network?